# Is it possible to analyze how frequent the ERC721/1155 `tokenURI` method is called?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, events, erc-1155

The ERC721/1155 method `tokenURI` is a public variable and has a getter for retrieving the data itself (e.g., often returns the `ipfs://Qm...` CID). Let's assume the `tokenURI` method itself isn't emitting some sort of event when it's called since the only events that are part of the specification are `Transfer`, `Approval`, and `ApprovalForAll`. If it did emit an event, then one could simply parse logs for when this method is called.

So, is it possible to know how often `tokenURI` is called across Ethereum as a whole, or at a minimum, for a single ERC721/1155 contract? With centralized services like Infura or Etherscan, they likely have that type of data in-house, but it's not publicly accessible -- e.g., how many times `tokenURI` is called via API (or through the UI) across everyone that uses their respective services.

The general goal is to understand Ethereum's most used ERC721/1155 contract methods while highlighting the frequency of `tokenURI` reads. I wasn't able to find this exact type of information on [Dune.xyz](https://dune.xyz/) nor [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/), so I'm curious if I'm just unaware of how straightforward this is...or it's just not possible due to no events being logged.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine this actually. And if you do choose to emit events in the tokenURI function it would no longer be a `view` i.e. it mutates the state of blockchain, since logs(events) are stored in the blockchain database and you'd require a tx to do that. Even if you do make a function that will emit events, most likely people are just going to `eth_call` it, no one is going to pay for reading data from blockchain. Nor should they.

Also, mutability of a function is a part of standard, so a mutable `tokenURI` will not really be metadata extensions compliant standard. See metadata extensions [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specification).

In conclusion, it is not possible to get this data without a very custom RPC that will log and track the `eth_call`s. And even then you'd only get the data for and about the people using that RPC which will only be a subset of users. Major providers like infura, alchemy can track this to give some idea of it.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Appreciate the detail!